# Reshaping pandas dataframe - (Pivot/Stack-unstack)

Tags: pandas, stack, reshape

I have dataframe like this:

[image: Previous data]
i want to reshape it to:

[image: Desired data]

I Have tried:
`df2.pivot(index ='color', columns ='quarter')` but getting error

`KeyError: 'color'`
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Also Stack and unstack but not getting desired result. Please help.

Comment: What is `print (df2.info())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'color':list('abcabc'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'quarter':['FY2015_16_Q1'] * 3 + ['FY2015_16_Q2'] * 3 
}).set_index(['quarter','color'])

print (df2)
                    B  C  D
quarter      color         
FY2015_16_Q1 a      4  7  1
             b      5  8  3
             c      4  9  5
FY2015_16_Q2 a      5  4  7
             b      5  2  1
             c      4  3  0

print (df2.index)
MultiIndex([('FY2015_16_Q1', 'a'),
            ('FY2015_16_Q1', 'b'),
            ('FY2015_16_Q1', 'c'),
            ('FY2015_16_Q2', 'a'),
            ('FY2015_16_Q2', 'b'),
            ('FY2015_16_Q2', 'c')],
           names=['quarter', 'color'])
```

---

```
df = df2.unstack(0).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=0)
```

Or [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with `unstack`:

```
df = df2.stack().unstack([0,2])
```

---

```
print (df)
quarter FY2015_16_Q1       FY2015_16_Q2      
                   B  C  D            B  C  D
color                                        
a                  4  7  1            5  4  7
b                  5  8  3            5  2  1
c                  4  9  5            4  3  0
```